# how to set sql server filed date to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

i cant insert for using c# language DateTime.Now.ToString()

insert sqlserver in datatype datetime field

Comment: You can insert a date to SQL Server as YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of your localization and it will work every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't convert your `DateTime` value to a string. Use parameterised SQL instead:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Your_Table (Your_Column) VALUES (@YourParam)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourParam", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = yourDate;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt have to perform ToString() in order to insert to an SQL server db

Answer (score -1):

Your question didn't make a lot of sense, but I think you're looking for this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(string format)
```

That'll format the DateTime in the way you want it to.

Yous really shouldn't be building your SQL queries as strings in the first place, though. You should be using parameters, which allow you to give a C# non-string object rather than a converted string.

Comment: Also, read http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx. Specifically, look at the SQL parameters stuff - it's what you need.

Comment: Indeed, MM/dd/yyyy, mm = minutes.